# Can I use regular expression to find file name in Vertica?

Tags: regex, select, vertica

I need to load data from a flat file into Vertica. For example, I can use `SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM '/test/dir/Data20140501-070205.txt' ON ANY NODE` when the file name is `Data20140501-070205.txt`. However, the file name is not always the same.

The part before the hyphen stays the same, but the part after the hyphen can be changed.

Is it possible to use regular expression in the select statement to find the file name?

Comment: Does [REGEXP_LIKE](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/RegularExpressions/REGEXP_LIKE.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%20Reference%20Manual%7CSQL%20Functions%7CRegular%20Expression%20Functions%7C_____4) for you?

Comment: ^ and something like: [`Data20140501-\d+\.txt$`](http://regex101.com/r/fT7dB8)...

Answer (score 2):

I think your question isn't 100% accurate, so I'm going to answer what I think you are really asking.  I think you are looking for a way to load data using wildcards.  I'm guessing this because you included something close to a COPY statement and it looks like you are trying to load data.

The [COPY statement](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPY.htm) [supports globbing](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/SpecifyingCOPYFROMOptions.htm).

```
COPY tablename (COL1, COL2, COL3) 
FROM '/test/dir/Data20140501-*.txt' ON ANY NODE;
```